# query builder write sql 'WHERE total = %s' % (n,)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

In Laravel, how to write following sql statements:

```
SELECT n
FROM table
WHERE table.id = %s % (10,)
```

using query builder or Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Laravel code might look something like:

```php
$entities = DB::table('your_table')
    ->where('id', '=', 10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code look something like below

```
DB::table('your_table')
->where('id', 10)
->get();
```

[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)